# I'm getting my forecast point in R to be negative

Tags: r, forecast

[image: plot of the forecast]

After printing the forecasted values in R I'm getting all forecasted points to be negative and when I plot the forecasted values I get x values of the plot to be in negative

the x values should be positive not negative

```
M1 = auto.arima(`Number of Daily Admissions`, stepwise = FALSE,approximation = FALSE,trace = TRUE)

forecast_values <- forecast(M1, h = 90, level = c(80))

print(forecast_values)
```

Comment: What is the output of `dput(head(`Number of Daily Admissions`))`?

Comment: > dput(head(`Number of Daily Admissions`))
structure(c(1, 2, 4, 0, 2, 2), tsp = c(-2012, -2011.98630136986, 
365), class = "ts")

Comment: So it looks like your data was incorrectly loaded/created, where your time series is set up in year -2012.

Comment: how do i do that then

Comment: How did you load/create your data?

Comment: Maybe `ts(rev('Number of Daily Admissions'), start = 2012.0, end = 2012.5, frequency = 12)`?